How the script is running infinitely?
I am trying to understand the code below. How is it running infinitely? As per my understanding, once it reaches the while loop, it should never come out and should never print the messages received from the stream. But it is receiving the messages and printing them.
import asyncio
import ssl
from nats.aio.client import Client as NATS
from nats.aio.errors import ErrConnectionClosed, ErrTimeout, ErrNoServers

async def main():
    nc = NATS()


    options = {
        "servers": ["nats://nats.local:4222"]
    }
    
    async def callback(msg):
        print(f'Received: {msg.data.decode()}')
        
    try:
        await nc.connect(**options)
        print("Connected to NATS server")
        js = nc.jetstream()
        subject_input = "loan.application.details.input"
        
        stream_name = "UPDATES"
        
        sub = await js.subscribe(subject=subject_input, stream=stream_name, cb=callback)
        print(f"Subscribed to {subject_input} on stream {stream_name}")

        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    except ErrConnectionClosed:
        print("Connection closed")
    except ErrTimeout:
        print("Connection timeout")
    except ErrNoServers:
        print("No NATS servers available")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Interrupted")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    finally:
        await sub.unsubscribe()
        await nc.close()
        print("Closed connection")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())



I tried debugging the code in vs code but it is making me more confused.

It is simply that the js.subscribe call can create asyncio tasks on the running event loop, but it doesn't need to await until they are complete: each (or even if it is one) task it creates then can run when your code pauses awaiting for the asyncio.sleep.
That is simply how async programming creates concurrency - although it may not be perceivable when people do a common task like writting API views to run in async frameworks - because those are co-routines that are the "leaves" of the running tasks that are orchestrated by the framework.
In this case, the call to js.subscribe schedule its internal tasks.
